# SSRS - Passing parameter to run stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, drillthrough

I have set up a report in SSRS which drills through to a 2nd report. The data in the second report is a stored procedure that has a parameter declared, as in:

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure] (@Parameter VARCHAR(max)) AS.....

In the first report I have set up the Action on the text box properties to run the second report using the relevant parameter from the first report.

I am designing this in Visual Studio and when I 'Preview' the report in here it works correctly and the drillthrough passes through the parameter as intended. However when I deploy this onto our server and try to view the report using Internet Explorer the drill through doesn't work, I get an error saying that the parameter is read-only and cannot be modified.

From reading other posts relating to this online people have mentioned changing the parameter visibility to 'Visible' however this hasn't worked on mine.

Has anyone else experienced anything similar to this before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common problem when passing a parameter to a subreport. Have you seen this solution? http://saiabhilash.blogspot.nl/2012/05/report-parameter-is-read-only-and.html

Comment: Thanks for that, I think that's put me on the right track. I now have another issue where the 2nd report is asking for credentials even though I have tried hardcoding the login details in the connection string. I'm sure I can figure this one out on my own though.

Comment: Have you set the data sources in the properties of the report in Reporting Services (not in VS)?

Comment: Originally in Data Sources I had it set to connect using windows credentials which was working for the first report but not for the drill through. I have now set both of these to 'Credentials stored securely in the report server' and added login credentials